# Lost events inside ascx in some cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have some strange behavior.

I have a control (`InformationalPanel.ascx`) who is put inside two diferent aspx pages. In one of them (`SendSmsFile.aspx` ) everythings works fine but in other (`SendMessage.aspx`), although the control is correctly render, the events inside doesn't work.

The control is equal inside aspx pages who have equal asp header and same masterpage

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="SendMessage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Messages.SendMessage" ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

...

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelSubmissionScheduler" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <uc2:InformationalPanel ID="submissionSchedulerInformationalPanel" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The control has a repeater with a LinkButton who in some cases lost Click event

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterPartsToSchedule" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repeaterPartsToSchedule_ItemCommand"
                OnItemDataBound="repeaterPartsToSchedule_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    ...
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="scheduleLinkButton" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:ResourcesDefault, Schedule %>"
                        CssClass="button_serv" CommandName="schedule" OnClick="scheduleLinkButton_Click" />
                    ...
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

When visibility is changed (because some business rules) I call ascx's `Refresh` method who populates the repeater (DataBind).

I run debug in the to aspx pages but I cannot discover why in one everything works and in another the events (`scheduleLinkButton_Click` or `repeaterPartsToSchedule_ItemCommand`) isn't fire!

Hope I was explicit enough and sorry for my english

Thanks

Comment: You have verified the postback is happening?  On postback, can you check that `Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]` is about what you'd expect (e.g., compare the page which works to the one which does not)?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you don't bind your control every time,

```
You can use in your bind this bloc

If(! IsPostBack)
{

}
```

Comment: The control is binding only when Refesh method is called. The Refresh method is called once when I change the control visibility.